# Remove vim status bar background color?

Tags: gvim

How can I remove the horrible color of my vim status bar has? I'd like it to be the same color as the background.

[image]

My current settings in my `~./.vimrc` file (or `~/.vimrc.after` file as I use) which relate to the status bar are:

```
set laststatus=2                            " Show the last status
hi statusline guibg=#263238

set statusline=%f                           " Filename

function! InsertStatuslineColor(mode)
  if a:mode == 'i'
    hi statusline guibg=#573E81 guifg=#263238
  elseif a:mode == 'r'
    hi statusline guibg=blue guifg=#263238
  else
    hi statusline guibg=red guifg=#263238
  endif
endfunction

au InsertEnter * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertChange * call InsertStatuslineColor(v:insertmode)
au InsertLeave * hi statusline guibg=#c5c8c6 guifg=#263238

" default the statusline to green when entering Vim
hi statusline guibg=#c5c8c6 guifg=#263238
```

I am using MacVim v7.4 (88).

Comment: does setting the statuslinecolor not work?

Answer (score 3):

There are several places in the code where you specifically set the statusline background to a sort of grayish colour with commands like:

```
hi statusline guibg=#c5c8c6 ...
```

You need to replace these with lines like:

```
hi statusline guibg=NONE ...
```

...to remove the colour.

If your statusline background still isn't correct you might have also have `reverse` set. Check if the output of `:hilight statusline` contains `gui=reverse`.

If so, you will also need to clear this setting, like so:

```
hi statusline guibg=NONE gui=NONE ...
```

See `:help :highlight` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

In vim, typing

```rc
highlight clear StatusLine
```

worked for me

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Note that this will clear *all* colors from normal status line text